# textbox in gridview needs rich text editing; superscript, greaterthanequalto etc

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, editor, richtextbox

I've got an ASP.NET page with VB.NET backend.  It has a gridview, and users need to be able to edit the values in it.

It's dollar amount ranges that they are entering, and they need to be able to add superscript numbers at the end on occasion.  The standard asp.net textbox does not support these features, nor is there a way for users to enter the greater than or equal to symbols.

I'm looking for a straight forward solution, we had been using the FCKEditor, but this was incredibly clunky, and I was trying to find something more like the inline editing of ckEditor for the duration.

The newer version of CKEditor seems to be built for textarea, and not asp:textbox, which is what the gridview uses for the edit template field.  Anyone know any quick solutions for getting this functionality into a gridview edit mode textbox?

Additionally - I would settle for a back end conversion, where the user could enter "=<" and I could change it the appropriate symbol before storing it in the db... however, using

```
HTTPUtility.HTMLEncode(strValue.Replace("=<", "&#8804;"))
```

just gives me "&#8804;$500,000.00" which is worse...

Comment: You can post that comment as an answer to your own question.

Comment: opps :/ thx... clicked the wrong box :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's what I did to solve this: I had the users enter "<=" or whatever for the ranges, and add a "^" prior to any superscript. Then I replaced the 2 characters with the Unicode values, and did an Decode on the string. For the superscript, I replaced the carrot with the "sup" tag, and added the closing tag at the end of the string. it's a bit of a hack, but the users can enter what they need, and the values get stored properly, and displayed correctly afterwords.